# как обновить python3 и pip3 на linux mint mate 17

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, linux-mint, pip

решил поставить linux, дабы учиться с ним работать, но вот не задача,  пишу на python3 и стандартно тут стоит python3.4, я вроде смог поставить python3.6, но не могу установить pip3, примерно такое я получаю в терминале

```
artut1214@usser ~ $ pip3 install bs4 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1479, 
in <module>
    register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, 
DefaultProvider)
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 
'SourceFileLoader'
```

я в linux полный новичок, могу только команды которые скажете писать, облазил весь `stackoverflow`, и другие сайты, ничего не помогает

P.S. сам `python 3.6` работает нормально, и `pip` для python2 тоже

Comment: Для начала, два момента: 1) Если Вы используете третий питон, то зачем явно пишите pip3 ? Попробуйте сопоставить версии выполнив команды: *pip -V* и  *pip3 -V*. Думаю, получите одно и тоже. 2) Для выполнения **установки** любого ПО в Linux (как правило) требуются права root. Попробуйте сделать так: *sudo pip install bs4*

Comment: *не могу установить pip3* - Не понял! Ведь эта программа у Вас уже установлена! О чём свидетельствует тот очевидный факт, что она ЗАПУСКАЕТСЯ.  Да и ошибка происходит в файле */usr/bin/pip3*. Т.е. он уже имеется.

Comment: Ну и напоследок - зачем Вы ставите *bs4*?! Пакет вкусного супа устанавливается в третьем питоне по умолчанию. В чём легко убедиться, запустив питон и введя команду *import bs4* Она отработает нормально.